# A container sort (or "Minecraft sort")

Tags: sorting, human-computing

Here's the problem: I have some $n$ ordered containers, each with $m$ slots. I have $p$ temporary slots that I can use to move items between containers. Sorting within containers is not costly, however moving items between containers is, so the more temporary slots that can be used to move items between containers, the better.

More succinctly:

- There are $n$ containers with $m$ indices.
- There is an always-accessible container with $p$ indices.
- The $p$-container starts empty.
- Only one $n$-container can be opened at a time.
- Switching which $n$-container is opened is costly, and should be minimized.
- Swapping items between the opened $n$-container and the $p$-container has the same cost as any normal swap. I.e. there is no additional cost for swapping items between the temporary container and the opened container.

Take this in the case of sorting Minecraft chests: this gives $m=p=27$. You can only open one chest at a time, but you can move items however you want between that chest and your inventory.

I want to sort my chests so that it's easier to find things. Strategies such as Bubble Sort and Selection Sort *could* work, but they would take a long time as they wouldn't take advantage of all 27 temporary spaces. Is there a sorting algorithm that's memorizable and executable by a human to efficiently sort between containers?

Comment: `moving items between containers is [costly]` please fully specify the cost model: "source" container to temporary, temporary to *source container*, temporary to a different container - anything else?

Comment: With $n = 2$, this looks a scenario for [the Stooge sort](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stooge_sort). TAoCP addressed a similar problem in the context of sorting with a single tape drive, using an example of a building with people on $n$ floors and a single elevator of capacity $p$ as the only means to reach one's destination floor, discussing *Karp's elevator algorithm*.

Comment: @greybeard Only one container can be "opened" at a time: When a container is opened, moving items between it and the temporary container is not costly. It is the switching of opened containers that is costly.

Comment: Please fully specify the cost model *in your above question*: edit it!

Comment: See also: Frederickson, G. N.; Guan, D. J.: [*Preemptive Ensemble Motion Planning on a Tree*](https://docs.lib.purdue.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1735&context=cstech) SIAM J Comput. Vol. 21 pp. 1130-1152.